# Detect Android Bluetooth LE/WLAN crashes

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

While developing a bluetooth app that scans for and connects to some peripherals in the background and testing it on different smartphones and tablets I encountered some bugs regarding the stability of bluetooth low energy.

There are numerous other reported problems. But all of them are pointing towards connection loss or data loss. There are some solutions provided which I've implemented.

But I encountered another issue. At some point after starting the app I'm not able to find any bluetooth low energy device in range, nor can I connect to a Wifi network or transmit data over it. Sometimes it happens after the ble error code 133, sometimes without this warning. Sometimes the last connection establishment is immediately closed afterwards. The system also reports all calls to be executed and all is working well (eg scan started succesfully).

In most cases it is sufficient to deactivate bluetooth and start a standard bluetooth device discovery. As it is done by [BluetoothCrashResolver](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Faltbeacon%2Fbluetooth%2FBluetoothCrashResolver.java)

Has anyone noticed this problem too and had an idea how to detect this type of failure and start the recovery procedure?

Answer (score 1):

I have face this problem in my last application but I did work arounnd for seach issue.
This problem occurs first time you have done connection successfully and you app crashed or you have closed but you did not call disconnect properly in code.
For the same I found the work around that is each time before discovering device fisrt call desconect method for Lescan and the again discover that worked for my application.